# WP7 custom control: ObservableCollection items added in control initialization are invisible in the control properies grid

Tags: windows-phone-7, wpf-controls

I'm trying to create WP7 custom control and wish to initialize ObservableCollection (list of items) on startup (add a first collection item).

When the control is added to ContentPanel in designer, I see this first item (added in LayoutRoot_Loaded event) in UI, but collection in the control properties grid is **empty**. Adding a new item in Collection Editor replaces the initially added item and after this everything works fine.

My question is: how to add an item to ObservableCollection (inside control during initialization) and make this item visible for the property editor?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you post the XAML/class for the custom control?

Answer (score 0):

XAML uses properties injection of data, so a regular dependency property of a collection type (think ItemsSource), shouldn't be a problem.

Your problem is most likely related to bad initialization of the internal collection. Also, you shouldn't mix up design-time, and run-time code and functionality.

For more detailed advice: post your code!

Comment: Thanks for your help! The problem was resolved by using DefaultInitializer and IProvideAttributeTable.